# Access: generating a .DOC file cannot be opened on an iDevice

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am generating a .DOC file in an old access-VBA application using the typical 
GetObject("", Word.Document) strategy.  I can open this .doc just fine in windows, however I cannot open it on an iPad\iPhone.  The strange thing is, if I open this .doc in MS word, save it again as a .doc, I can then open it on an iPad.

What do I have to do to ensure that this .doc gets saved as something that isn't "an invalid format" on an idevice?  Any ideas?

EDIT 1: 
I Found some code that looks like:
DoCmd.OutputTo ...,..., "Rich Text Format",... and am wondering if this is correct?

EDIT 2:
What I am seeing is DoCmd.OutputTo as a RTF is what the iDevices do not seem to like.  Any other way to go about doing this?

Comment: you tried to save it as docx?

Comment: Not sure how to do that in access..  but it is just a doc file.  Should also note that the size of the file saved in access is substantially smaller than what MS Word saves...

Comment: Yes..  The problem isn't with the GetObject portion so much as the DoCmd.OutputTo portion (I have just recently realized..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are actually saving the file in RTF (Rich Text Format), but giving it a .DOC extension. MS Word can figure out the difference, but the iPad cannot.

To get the file to open on both devices, give the document a `.RTF` extension instead of `.DOC`.